# Uploading an image file with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, file-upload, nightwatch.js

I'm running front-end tests using nightwatch.js using the Chrome Driver. I need to test that image uploading works properly, presumably through the provided file input since there are callbacks that run on a successful post.

I'm aware that this can be done using sendKeys method of the Selenium Web Driver.

How can you accomplish this using javascript and nightwatch.js?
Can you access the Selenium webdriver or an interface with it?

Comment: i'd be interested to see how a file is chosen, i didn't think such a thing was possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this for uploading image from local desktop

```
.setValue('input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve('/home/My-PC/Desktop/img.png'))
```

Comment: Am I the only one to need to have a .pause() after setting the value of a file input like this ?

Answer (score 2):

As someone above has mentioned, you can pass the absolute path to your input[type="file"] as if you were typing text into a field.

This uses nightwatch's `setValue` function. You can retrieve the current directory path using Node's `__dirname` global var.

For example:
`.setValue('#upload-input', __dirname + '\\upload.jpg')`

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you have put the double backslash there, after ```__dirname```? Cheers

Comment: @grayedfox: the backslash is an escape character to precede special chars.    In this example, you're escaping a backslash (special char that we want to use) with a backslash (the escape character denoting the following character should be interpreted literally).

Answer (score 1):

Use client.setValue function to set the absolute path of your image. Here is the working example in my project.

client.setValue('#editPictures .modal-body input[type="file"]', '/Users/testing/pictures/CAM00003.jpg');

Answer (score 1):

In my case there is a div with id="Upload Icon" which has input with type="file"

```
.setValue('//div[@id="Upload Icon"]/input[@type="file"]', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/categoryIcon.png'))
```

The above code working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
.setValue('#file-upload', require('path').resolve('C:/Users/Mihai/Desktop/test.png'))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackVoerflow. Please format your answer using markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

`.setValue('input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve('/home/My-PC/Desktop/img.png'))`

Only thing maybe others running into might the different versions of firefox where it didn't work 2 yrs back for a co-worker.