# Upload action using Nightwatch.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to create an action for nightwatch that will upload files to a given upload form. Is it possible to create that kind of action in nightwatch? The nightwatch is integrated into a nodejs application and is running in a selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoIT to create an executable for the upload action. Execute the executable using the exec function of the Node. Upload.exe is the executable file compililed from the AutoIt script.

```
 exec('START "" .\\src\\Resources\\Upload.exe', function(err) {
        console.log('err: ' + err);})
```

Comment: Is AutoIt a plugin for nightwatch, I have my own framework so if it is a standalone framework I cannot use that

Comment: Sorry for late reply, AutoIT is only for creating the executable which after creation can be used in any framework by simply executing the executable via script.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919673). 
The approved answer gives this solution:

```
.setValue('input#fileUpload', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/testfile.txt'))
```

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/223#issuecomment-56080658) at the discussion that led to this fix.

Comment: I already look into that but my problem is how can I access the file from a selenium server