# Can I use links in setValue in file upload using nightwatch

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

Can I use links in different site in setValue in file upload using nightwatch? I look up a link in stackoverflow and see this: [File Upload Testing in Nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919673/file-upload-testing-in-nightwatch-js) but the answer said that it will not work if the file is coming from 'http://localhost:3000/testfile.txt'. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no you can not specify the web server path.

You can read more about [here](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths#web).

What you can do is First download file and then use its absolutes or relative paths to upload.

Comment: Hi I am using selenium for my nightwatch, I cannot get the absolute path inside seleniu,m

Comment: @Dranier are you trying to get the current domain + /testfile.txt' ?