# How to choose file to input by nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Previously I used Webdriver IO for testing, but now I use nightwatch.js.

I have not found solutions in documentation (setValue() is not working)

Webdriver IO provides very simple command for that:

```js
.chooseFile("input", "./path/to/image")
```

But what I can do by using nightwatch.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command setValue('input', 'path/to/file') should work, check your file path.

By the way. This question has already been answered previously, check

- [File Upload Testing in Nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919673/file-upload-testing-in-nightwatch-js)
- [Uploading an image file with Nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440712/uploading-an-image-file-with-nightwatch-js)

Comment: I found the solution by changing css property of input[type=file] from
  `display: none;`
to
  `visability: hidden;`

Now I have the next working code:

`.setValue("input.hidden-file", require('path').resolve(__dirname + 'path'))`